# Non-native resolution forced in the Android game. How to get native?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, resolution

In order to give best experience to player, I want provide possibility to choose game resolution from low (best performance) to native (best quality). Sadly, some android devices forces game to run in decreased non-native resolution, and I found no way how to detect native resolution. For example - Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10'' (2016) - have native resolution 1920x1200, but game runs in 1440x900. Fonts and interface looks blurry and poor. It's strange, but our analytic show what about 40% this devices runs the game with native resolution. But not in my case.

So, I need solution.

First option - is to get (in some way) native resolution of the device. Screen.width/height, Screen.currentResolution - not helps. Screen.resolutions - alway empty. android.util.DisplayMetrics - also reports only decreased resolution.

Second option - restrict system (or Unity) to run the game in native resolution only. I checked Unity settings and manifest - found nothing..

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [*adaptive UI*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_user_interface).

If you are using NGUI, see [this thread](http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=1398.0). There are many examples on how to do that. The key component is `UIAnchor`.

> You can either make your UI modular using `UIAnchor` components, set the `UIRoot` to be manually sized (and lose pixel perfection), or you can create different layouts. One layout for the iPhone, and another for iPad, for example.

If you are using Unity3D UI, see *[Designing UI for Multiple Resolutions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)*.

Comment: Why? IMHO, that's the only solution to your problem.

Comment: I already have complex interface and can't afford refactoring.